Unable to add image to Excel file with Office Scripts
In Excel Office Scripts, I'm able to add an image to an Excel file with the script:
function main(workbook: ExcelScript.Workbook, idioma: string = "en", base64: string) {
    
      // Acrescenta a worksheet "Intro" na primeira posição
      try { workbook.addWorksheet("Intro").setPosition(0) } catch { };
      let sheet = workbook.getWorksheet("Intro");
    
      // 
      let base64Img: string;
      let base64ImgHTML: string;
    
      //Add image type to the pure base64
      base64Img = "data&colon;image/png;base64," + base64
    
      //Add HTML tags to base64 imgBase64
      base64ImgHTML = '<img src="' + base64Img + '"/>'
    
      //Declare and add the image
      let img = sheet.addImage(base64Img);
    
      //Change the image name
      img.setName("Welcome.jpeg");
    
    };

With the "base64" parameter entered, like:
PHN2ZyB3aWR0aD0iNDQxIiBoZWlnaHQ9IjMyNSIgeG1sbnM9Imh0dHA6Ly93d3cudzMub3JnLzIwMDAvc3ZnIiB4bWxuczp4bGluaz0iaHR0cDovL3d3dy53My5vcmcvMTk5OS94bGluayIgeG1sOnNwYWNlPSJwcmVzZXJ2ZSIgb3ZlcmZsb3c9ImhpZGRlbiI+PGRlZnM+PGNsaXBQYXRoIGlkPSJjbGlwMCI+PHJlY3QgeD0iNTgyIiB5PSI0NCIgd2lkdGg9IjQ0MSIgaGVpZ2h0PSIzMjUiLz48L2NsaXBQYXRoPjwvZGVmcz48ZyBjbGlwLXBhdGg9InVybCgjY2xpcDApIiB ...

But running the script with the following flow, it fails with error:
We were unable to run the script. Please try again.
Office JS error: Line 18: Worksheet addImage: The argument is missing or invalid".


How to fix this?


The argument of addImage is base64 payload string without header.

Try:
let img = sheet.addImage(base64)


btw, pls use Base64 to Image to validate the Base64 string and ensure it's a valid argument.



A sample code to take snapshot of cell C1 and insert as an image on sheet

function main(workbook: ExcelScript.Workbook) {
  //get Worksheet
  const firstWorksheet = workbook.getWorksheets()[0];
  const cell = firstWorksheet.getRange("C1")
  cell.setValue("ABC");
  cell.getFormat().getFill().setColor("00FF00");
  // get image
  let tableImage = cell.getImage();
  console.log(tableImage);
  // Add the image to the worksheet
  let imgShape = firstWorksheet.addImage(tableImage);
  imgShape.setName("Cell-C1");
}

Output:
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


I've chagend the code to: let img = sheet.addImage(base64) and validated the base64 string. It works perfectly, if the script is executed directly in Excel. When running the same script, from Power Automate, if fails.

Comment out addImage first. Add code line to write base64 to a cell and then run it with PA. You can validate the content of Body argument.

Got it. Using the validator, I get: Your browser cannot display the file as “image/svg+xml”.

Then you need to fix the upstream matter first.
